# Take current month range of dates from json response in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an application. I am getting a response from the AJAX request like this:

```js
{
  "country": "italy",
  "timeline": {
    "cases": {
      "1/22/20": 0,
      "1/23/20": 0,
      "1/24/20": 0,
      "1/25/20": 0,
      "1/26/20": 0,
      "1/27/20": 0,
      "1/28/20": 0,
      "1/29/20": 0,
      "1/30/20": 0,
      "1/31/20": 2,
      "2/1/20": 2,
      "2/2/20": 2,
      "2/3/20": 2,
      "2/4/20": 2,
      "2/5/20": 2,
      "2/6/20": 2,
      "2/7/20": 3,
      "2/8/20": 3,
      "2/9/20": 3,
      "2/10/20": 3,
      "2/11/20": 3,
      "2/12/20": 3,
      "2/13/20": 3,
      "2/14/20": 3,
      "2/15/20": 3,
      "2/16/20": 3,
      "2/17/20": 3,
      "2/18/20": 3,
      "2/19/20": 3,
      "2/20/20": 3,
      "2/21/20": 20,
      "2/22/20": 62,
      "2/23/20": 155,
      "2/24/20": 229,
      "2/25/20": 322,
      "2/26/20": 453,
      "2/27/20": 655,
      "2/28/20": 888,
      "2/29/20": 1128,
      "3/1/20": 1694,
      "3/2/20": 2036,
      "3/3/20": 2502,
      "3/4/20": 3089,
      "3/5/20": 3858,
      "3/6/20": 4636,
      "3/7/20": 5883,
      "3/8/20": 7375,
      "3/9/20": 9172,
      "3/10/20": 10149,
      "3/11/20": 12462,
      "3/12/20": 12462,
      "3/13/20": 17660,
      "3/14/20": 21157,
      "3/15/20": 24747,
      "3/16/20": 27980,
      "3/17/20": 31506,
      "3/18/20": 35713,
      "3/19/20": 41035,
      "3/20/20": 47021,
      "3/21/20": 53578,
      "3/22/20": 59138,
      "3/23/20": 63927,
      "3/24/20": 69176,
      "3/25/20": 74386,
      "3/26/20": 80589,
      "3/27/20": 86498
    },
    "deaths": {
      "1/22/20": 0,
      "1/23/20": 0,
      "1/24/20": 0,
      "1/25/20": 0,
      "1/26/20": 0,
      "1/27/20": 0,
      "1/28/20": 0,
      "1/29/20": 0,
      "1/30/20": 0,
      "1/31/20": 0,
      "2/1/20": 0,
      "2/2/20": 0,
      "2/3/20": 0,
      "2/4/20": 0,
      "2/5/20": 0,
      "2/6/20": 0,
      "2/7/20": 0,
      "2/8/20": 0,
      "2/9/20": 0,
      "2/10/20": 0,
      "2/11/20": 0,
      "2/12/20": 0,
      "2/13/20": 0,
      "2/14/20": 0,
      "2/15/20": 0,
      "2/16/20": 0,
      "2/17/20": 0,
      "2/18/20": 0,
      "2/19/20": 0,
      "2/20/20": 0,
      "2/21/20": 1,
      "2/22/20": 2,
      "2/23/20": 3,
      "2/24/20": 7,
      "2/25/20": 10,
      "2/26/20": 12,
      "2/27/20": 17,
      "2/28/20": 21,
      "2/29/20": 29,
      "3/1/20": 34,
      "3/2/20": 52,
      "3/3/20": 79,
      "3/4/20": 107,
      "3/5/20": 148,
      "3/6/20": 197,
      "3/7/20": 233,
      "3/8/20": 366,
      "3/9/20": 463,
      "3/10/20": 631,
      "3/11/20": 827,
      "3/12/20": 827,
      "3/13/20": 1266,
      "3/14/20": 1441,
      "3/15/20": 1809,
      "3/16/20": 2158,
      "3/17/20": 2503,
      "3/18/20": 2978,
      "3/19/20": 3405,
      "3/20/20": 4032,
      "3/21/20": 4825,
      "3/22/20": 5476,
      "3/23/20": 6077,
      "3/24/20": 6820,
      "3/25/20": 7503,
      "3/26/20": 8215,
      "3/27/20": 9134
    }
  }
}
```

As you can, I have dates for the month of February and March in this response. I want to get only the range of dates with the corresponding value within the current month, that is March in this case. How can I achieve this in jQuery?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/italy',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log('in');
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: When you say 'within the current month' do you mean literally only the dates in March, or do you mean any date in the last N days?

Comment: @cadamerx Check my implementation. You get more stats.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) & [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods to acheive this like:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/italy',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    const date = new Date(),y = date.getFullYear(),m = date.getMonth();
    const firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1).getTime(), lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getTime();
    const currentData = Object.keys(data.timeline.cases)
      .filter(key => firstDay <= new Date(key).getTime() && new Date(key).getTime() <= lastDay)
      .reduce((o, k) => { o[k] = data.timeline.cases[k]; return o }, {});
    console.log(currentData)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Explanation:

1. First inside ajax success method, we are trying to get first & last day of the current month, as we need those values to filter data.
2. Then using `Object.keys` we get all the keys in `data.timeline.cases` as this holds all the date strings as key.
3. Then using `filter()` method we get only the keys which are between first and last day of the current month.
4. Then using `reduce()` method we are trying to reconstruct the `data.timeline.cases` object back, so that you can use it in your application.

Comment: This is very nice. What if I want to get the date and value from the beginning, but on a frequency of 15 days ? 01 Jan - 15 Jan - 01 Feb, 15 Feb and so on ?

Comment: Please create a separate question for that so that there is no mixup and user can help you with a detailed answer regarding one specific issue at a time. Though that logic also should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `$.each()` to determine whether the key in the `cases` object is a date within the current month and use it to create a new object with those entities. Try this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical/italy',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    var currentMonthCases = {};
    $.each(data.timeline.cases, (k, v) => {
      if (new Date(k).getMonth() === currentMonth)
        currentMonthCases[k] = v;
    })
    
    console.log(currentMonthCases);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is very nice. What if I want to get the date and value from the beginning, but on a frequency of 15 days ? 01 Jan - 15 Jan - 01 Feb, 15 Feb and so on ?

Answer (score 0):

**Using map, reduce, you can do is very easly. I have written a  parser, will give you more stats. Please check.**

```js
const data = {
  country: "italy",
  timeline: {
    cases: {
      "1/22/20": 0,
      "1/23/20": 0,
      "1/24/20": 0,
      "1/25/20": 0,
      "1/26/20": 0,
      "1/27/20": 0,
      "1/28/20": 0,
      "1/29/20": 0,
      "1/30/20": 0,
      "1/31/20": 2,
      "2/1/20": 2,
      "2/2/20": 2,
      "2/3/20": 2,
      "2/4/20": 2,
      "2/5/20": 2,
      "2/6/20": 2,
      "2/7/20": 3,
      "2/8/20": 3,
      "2/9/20": 3,
      "2/10/20": 3,
      "2/11/20": 3,
      "2/12/20": 3,
      "2/13/20": 3,
      "2/14/20": 3,
      "2/15/20": 3,
      "2/16/20": 3,
      "2/17/20": 3,
      "2/18/20": 3,
      "2/19/20": 3,
      "2/20/20": 3,
      "2/21/20": 20,
      "2/22/20": 62,
      "2/23/20": 155,
      "2/24/20": 229,
      "2/25/20": 322,
      "2/26/20": 453,
      "2/27/20": 655,
      "2/28/20": 888,
      "2/29/20": 1128,
      "3/1/20": 1694,
      "3/2/20": 2036,
      "3/3/20": 2502,
      "3/4/20": 3089,
      "3/5/20": 3858,
      "3/6/20": 4636,
      "3/7/20": 5883,
      "3/8/20": 7375,
      "3/9/20": 9172,
      "3/10/20": 10149,
      "3/11/20": 12462,
      "3/12/20": 12462,
      "3/13/20": 17660,
      "3/14/20": 21157,
      "3/15/20": 24747,
      "3/16/20": 27980,
      "3/17/20": 31506,
      "3/18/20": 35713,
      "3/19/20": 41035,
      "3/20/20": 47021,
      "3/21/20": 53578,
      "3/22/20": 59138,
      "3/23/20": 63927,
      "3/24/20": 69176,
      "3/25/20": 74386,
      "3/26/20": 80589,
      "3/27/20": 86498
    },
    deaths: {
      "1/22/20": 0,
      "1/23/20": 0,
      "1/24/20": 0,
      "1/25/20": 0,
      "1/26/20": 0,
      "1/27/20": 0,
      "1/28/20": 0,
      "1/29/20": 0,
      "1/30/20": 0,
      "1/31/20": 0,
      "2/1/20": 0,
      "2/2/20": 0,
      "2/3/20": 0,
      "2/4/20": 0,
      "2/5/20": 0,
      "2/6/20": 0,
      "2/7/20": 0,
      "2/8/20": 0,
      "2/9/20": 0,
      "2/10/20": 0,
      "2/11/20": 0,
      "2/12/20": 0,
      "2/13/20": 0,
      "2/14/20": 0,
      "2/15/20": 0,
      "2/16/20": 0,
      "2/17/20": 0,
      "2/18/20": 0,
      "2/19/20": 0,
      "2/20/20": 0,
      "2/21/20": 1,
      "2/22/20": 2,
      "2/23/20": 3,
      "2/24/20": 7,
      "2/25/20": 10,
      "2/26/20": 12,
      "2/27/20": 17,
      "2/28/20": 21,
      "2/29/20": 29,
      "3/1/20": 34,
      "3/2/20": 52,
      "3/3/20": 79,
      "3/4/20": 107,
      "3/5/20": 148,
      "3/6/20": 197,
      "3/7/20": 233,
      "3/8/20": 366,
      "3/9/20": 463,
      "3/10/20": 631,
      "3/11/20": 827,
      "3/12/20": 827,
      "3/13/20": 1266,
      "3/14/20": 1441,
      "3/15/20": 1809,
      "3/16/20": 2158,
      "3/17/20": 2503,
      "3/18/20": 2978,
      "3/19/20": 3405,
      "3/20/20": 4032,
      "3/21/20": 4825,
      "3/22/20": 5476,
      "3/23/20": 6077,
      "3/24/20": 6820,
      "3/25/20": 7503,
      "3/26/20": 8215,
      "3/27/20": 9134
    }
  }
};

const parseDate = srt => {
  const [m, d, y] = srt.split("/");
  return new Date(d, m - 1, y).getMonth();
};
const toArray = obj => {
  const generator = function*() {
    for (let key in obj) {
      yield [obj[key], key];
    }
  };
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]: generator,
    map: function(fn) {
      let result = [];
      for (let [value, key] of this) {
        result.push(fn(value, key));
      }
      return result;
    }
  };
};
const grouped = toArray(data.timeline.cases)
  .map((x, k) => [x, k])
  .reduce((m, c) => {
    const parsedDate = parseDate(c[1]);
    if (!m[parsedDate]) {
      m[parsedDate] = { cases: [], deaths: [], totalCases: 0, totalDeaths: 0 };
    }
    m[parsedDate].cases.push({ date: c[1], cases: c[0] });
    m[parsedDate].deaths.push({
      date: c[1],
      deaths: data.timeline.deaths[c[1]]
    });
    m[parsedDate].totalCases += c[0];
    m[parsedDate].totalDeaths += data.timeline.deaths[c[1]];
    return m;
  }, {});
// console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped, null, 2));
// For march
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped[2], null, 2));
console.log(grouped[2].totalDeaths);
console.log(grouped[2].totalCases);
// For feb
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped[1], null, 2));
console.log(grouped[1].totalDeaths);
console.log(grouped[1].totalCases);
```

Comment: This is very nice. What if I want to get the date and value from the beginning, but on a frequency of 15 days ?
01 Jan - 15 Jan - 01 Feb, 15 Feb and so on ?

Comment: you just has to change parseDate function, all work as simple.

Comment: change parseDate to

`const parseDate = srt => {
  let [m, d, y] = srt.split("/");
  if(d > 15) d = "2"
  else d = "1"
  return `${m}_${d}`;
};`

March ist half:
`console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped["3_1"], null, 2));`